# How to remove spaces from string only if it occurs once between two words but not if it occurs thrice?

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner working on a diff and regenerate algorithm but for Strings. I store the patch in a file. To regenerate the new string from old I use that file. Although the code works, I face a problem when using space.

I use `replaceAll(" ", "");` for removing spaces. This is fine when the string is [char][space][char], but creates problem when it is like [space][space][space]. Here, I want that the space be retained(only one).

I thought of doing `replaceAll("   ", " ");`. But this would leave spaces in type [char][space][char]. I am using scanner to scan through the string.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
Input      Output
 c      => c
cc      => cc
c c     => cc
c  c    => This is not possible. Since there will be padding of one space for each character
c   c   => c c
```

Comment: What if there is 5 spaces next to each other?  Do you only want 1 space left or what?

Comment: Remember, `replaceAll` uses a regex. If what you are replacing is a constant string, you can just use `replace`.

Comment: @azro Do you know, how I can achieve this?

Comment: You could use regex *lookarounds* to check whether your space is surrounded by other spaces.

Comment: Could you give more examples ?

Comment: @Nexevis Yes only one space. Those between characters have to remove but those space between spaces are to be kept as it is. This is because they are part of the original/old string. The additional spaces between characters are just padding that were done by diff algorithm

Comment: So 1-2 space => 0 space, and 3-more space => 1space ?

Comment: @MCEmperor I would appreciate it if you could ellaborate a little more? About their use in java. I am not well-versed in regex.

Comment: @azro No. If 1 space it means the space is for padding and if 3 spaces then only 1 space must be kept and other two removed

Comment: Please details for all different cases, by editing your post

Comment: maybe `replaceAll(" (.|$)", "$1")`

Comment: *"This is not possible"* Don't say that, your code will be brittle. Say "This should not be possible, but do *(this)* if it happens anyway". Always define the rules, even for exceptions. Said another way: There are no exceptions, only rules.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. Also, I because that is how the code works. Although you are right. Thanks

Comment: Defensive programming: Expect the unexpected.

Comment: Can you put quotes around the inputs so we know where they start and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *lookarounds* to do your replacement:

```
String newText = text
    .replaceAll("(?<! ) (?! )", "")
    .replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

The first `replaceAll` removes any space not surrounded by spaces; the second one replaces the remaining sequences of spaces by a single one.

[Ideone example](http://ideone.com/4NCqwN). Sequences of two or more spaces become a single space, and single spaces are removed.

#### Lookarounds

A *lookaround* in the context of regular expressions is a collective term for *lookbehind*s and *lookahead*s. These are so-called *zero-width assertions*, that means they match a certain pattern, but do not actually consume characters. There are positive and negative lookarounds.

A short example: the pattern `Ira(?!q)` matches the substring `Ira`, but only if it's not followed by a `q`. So if the input string is `Iraq`, it won't match, but if the input string is `Iran`, then the match is `Ira`.

**More info:**

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

We can also split the string on where there are more than one white space, then join the resulting array by into a string using the `Stream` and `Collector` API.

Also we would replace the single spaces by using `replaceAll()` in a `Stream#map` operation:

```
String test = "   this    is a test of     space in string    ";
//using the pattern \\s{n,} for splitting at multi spaces
String[] arr = test.split("\\s{2,}");
String s = Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .map(str -> str.replaceAll(" ", ""))
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
 this isatestof spaceinstring
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace any group of space by one you could use:

```
value.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
```

Comment: This would not remove spaces in between `char space char` and would leave it untouched however.  Going off of his previous attempt he makes it seem like he wants it `char char` for that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use two replacements:

```
String e = "a b   c";
e = e.replaceAll("([A-Z|a-z])\\s([A-Z|a-z])", "$1$2");
e = e.replaceAll("   "," ");
System.out.println(e);
```

Which prints

> ab c

The first one replaces any letter-space-letter combo with just the two letters, and then the second replaces any triple-space with a single space.

The first replacement is using backreferences. $1 refers to the part inside the first set of parenthesis that matches the first letter, and $2 refers to the part inside the second set of parenthesis.

If you have leading/trailing spaces on the input, you can call trim() before doing the replacements.

```
e = e.trim()
```

Comment: This does not work for spaces in front of the string.

Comment: @arcadeblast77 Fixed it.

Comment: @arowell The original question does require that *one* space should be retained when the input has multiple spaces in a row. `trim` would nuke all of the spaces and break this requirement for some inputs.